# Reduce Priming Sugar

Tags: bottling, priming

I'm on my first batch of wort, I didn't account for evaporation and had a couple boil overs, I'm sitting at about 4.25 gallons of wort.  Bottling calls for 5oz of priming sugar, should I reduce to account for the lost .75 gal.?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should reduce the amount linearly. 5oz * (4.25gl/5gl) = 4.25oz.

EDIT: on second thought, 2.5 volumes isn't all that high. <del>Though: 5oz of sugar will result in a pretty high carbonation for 5gl of beer.  What sort of style?  At what temp will you be doing your bottle priming?</del>

I suggest using a [priming sugar calculator](http://www.tastybrew.com/calculators/priming.html) to get a better handle on how much of what type of priming sugar to use for your batch.

Comment: Here's another chart: http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter11-4.html. Use a straight edge to calculate an extrapolate to your volume